# Can't preview report when using datasets or .Net objects

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Crystal Reports only allows combo charts (bar + line) by going into the preview pane and using *Series Options...* on that screen and that screen only. It doesn't give any sample data like it does with SQL connections - even when I use an XSD as a data source or .Net class objects. Can I show random data just so I can access the series editor to modify the chart variables?

[image]

[image]

The preview screen shows an empty chart (no headers, axes, data, etc).

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no way in Crystal to preview a dataset without a dataset. Most developers tend to start by connecting to the tables they want to use, then add charts. (Evident in the New Report wizard.)

That said, *you* could make a preview dataset and temporarily connect to it to preview your charts. The table would only have to have one record in order to be a valid dataset, but you can make it as complex as needed for your testing needs.